# Creating triangulation from lines and curves

Tags: triangulation

In geography contours are created to the describe land heights. In computer graphics triangulation is required. Creating triangles from points is straightforward using the Delaunay rules. What is the mathematical algorithm for creating triangles from lines and curves?

Comment: If the curves are *polygonal* curves, the the key term is "constrained triangulation". Otherwise, do you mean triangles with curved edges?

Comment: Thanks "constrained triangulation" was what I was after. So GIS software like AutoCAD Map converts contours to polygonal curves and then to constrained triangulation. My questions would then be - 1. methods for converting curve to polygonal curve; 2. methods for converting polygonal curves to points as input for Delaunay triangulation